# SVG - scale circle from center

Tags: svg

I want to scale my arc that is embedded in svg. While apply scale transform, it is scaled towards 0, 0. Instead of that, i want it to be scaled center from it's own.

here is the code

```
<g>                 
    <path d="M 300 100 a 200 200 0 1 0 0.00001 0" fill="#7EEC4A" stroke="rgb(208,231,235)" linejoin="round" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.9" stroke-opacity="0.2">
    </path>

    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
        attributeName="transform"
        type="scale"
        from="0"
        to="1"
        dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" />
</g>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely satisfactory, because I've been unable to leave unchanged your original shape, but the effect required seems OK:

```
<g transform="translate(300,250)">
        <g>
            <path d="M 0 -150 a 200 200 0 1 0 0.00001 0" fill="#7EEC4A"
                stroke="rgb(208,231,235)" linejoin="round" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.9"
                stroke-opacity="0.2">
            </path>
            <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
                attributeName="transform"
                type="scale"
                from="0"
                to="1"
                dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" />
        </g>
    </g>
```

You may try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a5C6U/) fiddle

Answer (score 15):

Using the `<circle>` element and animating the "r" attribute:

```
<g>                 
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="200" fill="#7EEC4A" stroke="rgb(208,231,235)" linejoin="round" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.9" stroke-opacity="0.2">
        <animate attributeType="xml" attributeName="r" from="0" to="200" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />    
    </circle>
</g>
```

Comment: @ProllyGeek: I wonder if you noted that the answer doesn't address **any** of the problems in the question, starting from using **another**, simpler, shape than required...

Comment: @CapelliC You're quite right and newcomers to this technology need to understand the differences here.@ProllyGeek The question asked how to animate scale, not radius. While in effect the same visual for a circle, the implications of this concept as applied to other elements is far different. This should not be chosen as the correct answer.