# AngularJS css3-animate svg attribute

Tags: html, angularjs, css, svg, css-animations

Is it possible to animate the change of radius of a svg element?

```
<circle data-ng-attr-r='{{radius}}' />
```

all the examples I found either use javascript or have fixed css, things like

```
transition: 3s ease-out all
```

do not seem to pick-up the attribute `r` of `circle`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVG - scale circle from center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517988/svg-scale-circle-from-center)